# Which is the better way of relating these database tables?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, relational-database

I have a table `Users` and `Matters`. Ordinarily only admins can create a matter so I did a one to many relationship between users and matters(User.hasMany(Matter)) and (Matter.belongsTo(User))

Now on the frontend, `Matter` is supposed to have a multi-select field called `assignees` where users gotten from the `User` table can be selected.

My current approach is to make `assignees` a column on `Matter` which will be an array of user emails selected on the frontend but the frontend developer thinks I should make it an array of user ids instead but I think that won't be efficient because when getting all matters or updating them, one will need to run a query each time to get the associated assignees using the array of ids stored in the `assignees` column(and I am not entirely sure on how to go about that).

Another option is having a `UserMatters` join table but I don't think it will be performant-friendly to populate two tables(Matter and UserMatters) on creation of a matter while updating and getting all matters will involve writing lots of code.

My question is, is there a better way to go about this or should I just stick with populating the assignees field with user emails since it looks like a better approach as far as I can see?

**N.B: I am using sequelize(postgres)**

Comment: This is surely a case of premature optimization. "UserMatters join table but I don't think it will be performant-friendly ..." That is undoubtedly true. But without it you **cannot do** "Matter is supposed to have a multi-select field called assignees ..." unless you move assignees to user. In which case a user can only have 1 matter. The relation you need between Users and Matters is not a 1:M nor a M:1 it is a M:M. That requires the UserMatters table to resolve. Lesser performance on a design that satisfies requirements is far superior to blazing fast that  does not satisfy requirements.

Comment: @Belayer Thanks. I worked something out though.

Comment: Great. If you worked something out yourself, then post that as an answer and accept it. That is so any future questioner with the same issue sees a result. Please do not just leave it unanswered.

Comment: @Belayer I will do that now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did was instead of creating a through/join table, the frontend sent an array of integers containing the IDs of the assignees. Since the assignees are also users on the app, when I get a particular matter, I just loop through the IDs in the assignees column which is an array and get the user details from the user table then I reassign the result to that column and return the resource.

```
try {        
             // get the resource
            const resource = await getResource(id);
             /*looping through the column containing an array of IDs and converting it to numbers(if they are strings)**/
            let newArr = resource.assignees.map(id => Number(id));
            let newAssignees;

             /**fetch all users with the corresponding IDs and wait for that process to be complete**/
            newAssignees = await Promise.all(newArr.map(id => getUserById(id)));

            /**Returns only an array of objects(as per sequelize)**/
            newAssignees.map(el => el.get({ raw: true }));

            /**reassign the result**/
            resource.assignees = newAssignees;

            if(resource)
                return res.status(200).json({
                    status: 200,
                    resource
                })
            } else {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    status: 404,
                    message: 'Resource not found'
                });
            }
        } catch(error){
            return res.status(500).json({
                status: 500,
                err: error.message
            })
        }
```